# Cannot read property 'router' of undefined and ko is not defined in knockout JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, requirejs, durandal

I am learning Knockout js and package for Durandal.
While going through this tutorial 
http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro

I am facing some errors//

This is my viewmodel js file code --

```
    function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = "Bert";
    this.lastName = "Bertington";
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

This is my view html file code-

```
<p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
<p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
```

Error I am getting -

[image]

I have attempted to resolve those errors - I have defined ko in my code..

```
define(function (require) {
  var app = require('durandal/app'),
      ko = require('knockout');

function AppViewModel() {
        this.firstName = "Bert";
        this.lastName = "Bertington";
    }

    // Activates knockout.js
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

});
```

I am following some tutorials for that.. But I am facing some basic effects. May be those errors will be very basic but I need some assistance..

Thanks !!

Comment: please show your bootstrap file for requirejs.

Comment: if you are using durandal then there is no need to use ko.applyBindings.

Comment: What akhlesh is saying... Please note that it is not the best idea to combine the KnockoutJS tutorials with Durandal code, as you probably aren't advanced enough at Knockout yet to fully grasp what Durandal is doing. Also, look into RequireJS and the revealing module pattern to get a better understanding of creating code with the patterns Durandal/Require use.

Comment: Yes.. @akhlesh I am using Durandal..

Comment: @akhlesh what I understood.. No need to use that code if I am using durandal.. I can return the values.. directly..

Comment: @Coder check this [http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-Module.html](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-Module.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
define(['plugins/router', 'knockout', 'services/logger', 'durandal/app'], function (router, ko, logger, app) {

    var AppViewModel = {
            firstName : ko.observable("Bert"),
            lastName : ko.observable("Bertington")
        }

        // Activates knockout.js
        return AppViewModel;

});
```

or this

```
define(['plugins/router', 'knockout', 'services/logger', 'durandal/app'], function (router, ko, logger, app) {
    var AppViewModel = function () {
        this.firstName = "Bert";
        this.lastName = "Bertington";
    }

    // Activates knockout.js
    return new AppViewModel();
});
```